# Hide API token from generated .cshtml page source code

Tags: javascript, security, token, hide

I have a `.cshtml` page, where a click on a button calls an API

Currently, my JS code looks like :

```
var headers = {};
headers["Authorization-Token"] = '@Model.ApiToken';

$.ajax({
    url: "my-url",
    type: "GET",
    headers: headers
});
```

However, if the end-user opens the browser console, goes to the Network tab, searches for the generated `cshtml`, he can see :

```
var headers = {}
headers[Authorization-Token] = 'my_token'
```

The token can be seen in clear text
I can't call my API without this header, as the call is immediately rejected if the header is not present.

Is there a way to hide it to the end-user, and if so, how ?
Thank you

Comment: No, because even if you could hide it inside the JS, you can still view all network headers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep the tokens outside the browser, one option is to store the token inside the cookie (encrypted of course). ASP.NET Core can handle that for you automatically. Or in the backend as part of the user session.

An perhaps better option is to look at using the Backend For Frontend (a.k.a BFF) pattern to secure SPA applications.

See

- [Backend For Frontend Authentication Pattern with Auth0 and ASP.NET Core](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/)
- [The BFF Pattern (Backend for Frontend): An Introduction](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf)
- [Securing SPAs using the BFF Pattern (once and for all)](https://blog.duendesoftware.com/posts/20210326_bff/)